# video not playing on iOS safari

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, safari, mp4, playback

This video plays perfectly on Chrome Desktop and Android Chrome, on the latest releases.

However it won't work on an iPad and an iPhone.

[Video Link](https://storage.googleapis.com/clipdrop-prod/videos/questions/0_1_JLiemR1cH1AGMz5ca6gBJATNrrwVeEAGbuRPMaM5V68=.mp4?avoidCache=1)

also here is the file info.

[image]

Comment: File itself is fine. Play locally or upload it somewhere else and it will work.

Comment: @llogan that is the url that the phone receives, other links work, but these dont

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem related to ffmpeg or the file created by it. Seems more like a server-side issue.